# Do we need to have FAQ questions on Meta Web Applications about how Stack Exchange works (not specific to Web Applications)?

Tags: discussion, per-site-meta

I see a bunch of newly posted FAQ questions on Meta Web Applications SE about how Stack Exchange works (not specific to Web Applications):

- [Unlock badges for special achievements](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4902/18147)
- [Improve posts by editing or commenting](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4901/18147)
- [You earn reputation when people vote on your posts](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4900/18147)
- [Tags make it easy to find interesting questions](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4899/18147)
- etc.

Do we really need that on https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/?

I believe https://meta.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for it (it already has a [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq)) and that it's best if https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/ focuses on questions specific to Web Applications Stack Exchange.

Comment: Those FAQs are not pointed to users like you Frank that have accounts on multiple Stack Exchange sites and thousands of questions on them.

Comment: see also: [Cross-Site duplicates in meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225047/165773) "It is an intentional decision that the individual metas are pretty much on their own..."

Comment: I have no ideas if the downvotes mean yes or no (to the question: "do we need to have FAQ questions on Meta Web Applications about how Stack Exchange works (not specific to Web Applications)?")

Comment: Also a matter o local site culture, usually if more experienced users are involved in those metas they'll post a brief summary with references to the FAQ, MSE (and sometimes to MSO) depending where the best wiki is maintained or the most relevant discussion was held.

Answer (score 3):

The whole main meta is in a sense a ground source of truth, or primary reference, and most site metas have the same role of supporting their users we do. There's nothing wrong with asking how SE works in a per site meta.

It also puts help closer to where people need it - on an annex to the site, rather than a different site with its own rules and culture.

I would also feel that people finding help on local meta lends itself to a positive experience of the site.

Comment: "There's nothing wrong with asking how SE works in a per site meta." the issue is duplicating 183 times the same content. Especially for the FAQ.

Comment: Why is it an issue?  We didn't always have a 'real' network wide meta (this was MSO) and there's often nuances to specific sites. Its also 'friendlier' to be able to find/point out answers locally, even if its a commonly asked question. Most users are *not* going to be familiar with main meta either.

Comment: Harder to maintain (good luck to update the 183 copies if there's any changes), cluttering of per-site-Meta, and higher likelihood of incorrect/imprecise answers. In my original question I was targeting questions that aren't specific to a site. I don't care much anyway, just pointing out the inefficiency.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt AFAIK nobody had suggested to create / mantain 183 copies but many sites point  users struggling to solve problems around web apps to Web Applications SE, many of them are non tech savyy. P.S. The Tour of Meta SE hasn't the same content than the Tour of Web Applications SE.

Comment: @Rubén "many of them are non tech savyy. " maybe we could have an ELI5 version of the Meta SE [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) then (which other SE sites could also link to).

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt If you think that be of interest to the whole network please go ahead and propose the idea.

Comment: ELI5 versions of FAQ could and should be tailored to the sites. Also - after 13-14 years, I don't see the fundamental model of the sites changing all that much

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Many questions about how SE works don't need to be specific to an SE. Examples from the original question:  [Unlock badges for special achievements](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4902/18147);  [Improve posts by editing or commenting](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4901/18147);   [You earn reputation when people vote on your posts](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4900/18147);   [Tags make it easy to find interesting questions](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4899/18147)

Answer (score 2):

Web Applications SE moderator here, who migrated the question to Meta SE as this question might be more appropriate for it for several reasons.

## Meta Stack Exchange

The scope of this site is the whole Stack Exchange Network, but it does not go into the details of each site. The [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) (from Meta SE) might be helpful for users of all sites but might not be appropriate to the particular needs site by site.

Many users are not tech-savvy. Asking users that are struggling to understand how a site works to navigate to another site could make things more confusing for some of them.

There are several initiatives and [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)s related to address [new-user](/questions/tagged/new-user) needs like

- [Introducing new user onboarding project](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364572/289691) from 2021
- [Is it possible to make the tour more prominent to new users again?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383309/289691) from October 2022
- [Extending the "Your first question has been published, now what?" system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381420/289691) from August 2022

By the other hand, beside the scope, Meta Stack Exchange is unique among all the Stack Exchange sites,

1. It's the only "Meta" that award reputation to users
2. It works as it's own "per-site meta"
   It's the only site "main" site that has mandatory tags

### Meta Stack Exchange Tour

The Meta Stack Exchange Tour sections are different:

1. Welcome to Meta Stack Exchange
2. Ask questions about issues that affect all Stack Exchange sites
3. Be part of the community that decides how the sites work
4. Tags make it easy to find interesting questions

   - This looks similar but it isn't, as it explains the mandatory tags and the status tags.
5. Voting is different on meta sites
6. Unlock badges for special achievements

   - *This is similar*

## Web Applications

Since the end of the last year I become very concerned about the participation in Web Applications. I already made several posts about that and the FAQs that you refers are derived from them. Briefly, the idea in first place is to add explanations pointed to non-tech-savvy users that are new to Web Applications and to the Stack Exchange network. IMO, many of the FAQ in Meta SE posts might require to reworded to make them more appropriate for this audience.

The convenience of having a FAQ for the Tour results from my experience of reviewing for more than 8 years in Web Applications SE. I very frequently have found questions where the OP explicitly mentioned in one way or another not being teach savvy and on many opportunities of interacting with them have learned about the difficulties they have not only about the web application they are asking a question for, but for posting the question and learning the ropes of Web Applications SE.

Having a FAQ explaining each step of the tour is not *a panacea* (a remedy for all the difficulties) for the non-tech-savvy users, but it might help at least to make more evident to them that there is an active community interested on helping them.

By the way, here is the "intro" to the referred FAQs:

[Please explain the Web Applications Tour in simple words](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4895/88163)

## Summary

The Tour of Web Applications SE is specific for that site and even the title of the sections is standard. The FAQ about the Tour of Web Applications SE will address needs from non-tech-savvy users.

Use Meta Stack Exchange for

1. Asking questions / participate in discussions (some fun is allowed) about Stack Exchange in general, like the Stack Exchange model, the network history, network wide events like [winter-bash](/questions/tagged/winter-bash).
2. Asking for site recommendations
3. Report [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), make [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) about the platform that powers the all the Stack Exchange sites.

Use per-site meta

1. Asking question / participate in discussions about the corresponding site. Please bear in mind that while there are common base rules for all Stack Exchange site, each site has its own workings based on their own culture and circumstances.

   **Kind request to versatile Stack Exchange users**
   When participating in a per-site meta, please participate accordingly the local workings and culture. On small sites, the moderators are those who can better guide you to learn, and update about this.
2. Report `bug`, make `feature-request` about stuff that is specific for the corresponding site, i.e., there are parts of the Tour, Help Center, Ask Question, among other that could be customized for each site. Here are some related posts about the elements that can be customized on per site:

   - [Which elements of the frontpage can be customized per site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378042/289691) from April 2022
   - [The new ask page is now live on the network!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344513/289691) from March 2020

## Related

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/229875/289691
- [Are there best practices for individual sites to use their per-site-meta [faq] tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290991/289691)
- [Help specific to child meta sites should be more easily discovered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311381/289691)